# Override save to block all save, insert or update functionality in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP, if I override save function in AppModel to return false, will it stop any possible save, insert or update calls from happening? I need this to enable a read-only demo mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a beforeSave() callback, which always returns false. That should work.

Comment: beforeSave in AppModel returning false doesn't do anything?

Comment: I talk about an AppModel class in your application. And if you haven't already created a beforeSave() Callback there it should do nothing, because it doesn't exist. 
Of course every try to save something would then return an error to the user saying it could not be saved. 
If you don't want that then you might have to override the save function. 
Did you already try both approaches?

Comment: And if you have beforeSave() callbacks in the other models they might again override your callback in AppModel. So only you can decide which is the best approach depending on what you have coded so far.